# Declaring output file in mocha.opts configuration

Tags: mocha.js

Im trying to get Mocha reporter to output a html file, using the `mocha.opts` configuration file:

```
--compilers coffee:coffee-script/register
--reporter html-cov > tests.html
```

However this always returns the following:

```
→ mocha

/usr/local/lib/node_modules/mocha/bin/_mocha:432
  if (!files.length) throw new Error("cannot resolve path (or pattern) '"
                           ^
Error: cannot resolve path (or pattern) '>'
```

If I pass the command `mocha --reporter html-cov > testes.html` directly in the shell it does work.

What am I missing?

Comment: You're mistaking shell redirection (the ability to write a command's output to a file) with a mocha feature. It would be nice, however, to add that feature! You could add an issue asking for that in [the GitHub repo](https://github.com/visionmedia/mocha), and even try to implement it yourself.

Answer (score 3):

You can't put the redirection in `mocha.opts`. When you do it on the command line, the whole command is interpreted by the shell and `>` is understood to be a redirection. However the `mocha.opts` file is meant to be read as options and *only* options, nothing else. Mocha is not able to figure out that `> tests.html` is meant to be a redirection. You can put this in your `mocha.opts`:

```
--compilers coffee:coffee-script/register
--reporter html-cov
```

and keep `> tests.html` on the command line or use a wrapper script if you want to avoid typing it.

If there were an option to tell Mocha to output into a specific file (for instance, `--output file`) then you could put that in `mocha.opts` but Mocha has no such option right now.